# Активность элемента

Tags: jquery

У меня есть несколько спан-элементов, я вывожу в них размер товара. Подскажите как организовать такую штуку, чтобы при нажатии на элемент происходило его выделение, а потом при нажатии на след. элемент, происходило его выделение и автоматически снималось выделение с предыдущего элемента?

Comment: сделайте класс для выделенного элемента, скажем, selected. Создайте для этого класса соответствующие css-правила (рамка по краям, другой цвет фона или что-то в этом роде), затем при нажатии на соответствующий элемент присваивайте ему этот класс и вместе с тем удаляйте этот класс у остальных аналогичны элементов

Comment: какие методы для этого использовать?Я использую toogle , и как прописать все остальные элементы?у меня сейчас вот такой код $('span.COLOR').toggle(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("selected");
  }
);

Comment: ну вы же сами выше использовали - removeClass

Comment: да это понятно, я же не напишу сразу после добавления вот так $(this).removeClass("selected"), что должно быть перед точкой?

Comment: ваши спаны, у которых вы хотите удалить этот класс. Вам виднее, как они у вас называются

Comment: у всех спанов класс color))

у меня сейчас такой код, $('span.SIZE').toggle(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
$('span.SIZE').removeClass("selected");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("selected");
  }
);
 
чтобы выделить спан нужно нажать 2 раза)как от этого избавится?

Comment: ну и в чем же проблема? у них у всех и удаляйте

Comment: @santer545 сделайте jsfiddle, ничего не понятно, что у вас происходит

Answer (score 1):

```
$('span.SIZE').toggle( function () { $(this).addClass("selected"); $('span.SIZE').removeClass("selected"); }, function () { $(this).removeClass("selected"); } );
```

Comment: @santer545 еще раз говорю - сделайте jsfifddle. Из того, что вы тут показываете, сложно понять, в чем у вас проблема

Comment: мне приходится 2 раза нажимать на спан чтобы его выделить

Comment: что с этим делать??

Comment: как?я просто сегодня зарегистрировался тут.

Comment: существует замечательный сайт [jsfiddle.net][1], на котором можно выкладывать html, hs и css для подобных целей. Выложите на нем свой пример с html-разметкой, js-кодом и css, сохраните пример? нажмите вверху кнопку Save и дайте на него ссылку. Это поможет понять, что происходит у вас в коде

[1]:http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V762X/ вот ссылка, сама структура на битрикс, чтобы вы понимали что происходит, просто один за одним идут спан-ы, при нажатии на спан он должен становиться активным(добавляется тень)

Comment: @santer545 блин, вы и про разметку тоже не забудьте. А также про css. одного js мало

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V762X/1/ вот накидал пару спанов

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V762X/5/ добавил стиль

Answer (score 0):

вероятно, вам подойдет что-то вот такое: [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/af4RV/1/)

Comment: спасибо большое!!!!!!!Вы мне очень помогли!